# Why are there bullets before a H1 even though I did not write them?

Tags: html, css, header, bulletedlist

I am using MozBar plugin to check on my page performance and I recently noticed that all my H1 have a bullet before the actual title.

For example the code is:

```
<h1>Name of the page</h1>
```

but the MozBar shows the H1 to be:

- Name of the page

like I used a bulleted list for H1, which I didn't.

Does anyone know where this bullet might be coming from and how to delete it?

Thanks

Comment: Could there be a style that is getting applied to it ? Check your CSS files for the H1 Header styles.

Comment: You're asking what the feature means in the context of MozBar and how to disable it, is that right?